# 32Bit Bitmaps slow on Google TV. Bad Pixel format?

Tags: android, google-tv

I am wondering what I'm doing wrong here.

I create a bitmap with dimesions 1080x1080:

```
Bitmap level = Bitmap.createBitmap(1080, 1080, Config.ARGB_8888);
```

then I draw some lines and rects into it and put it on canvas in my SurfaceView:

```
c.drawBitmap(LevelBitmap.level, 0, 0, null);
```

and this operation takes 20ms on my google TV NSZ-GS7. much to long.

setting pixelformat in surfaceCreated to RGBX_8888 or RGBA_8888 makes things even worse, 30ms for drawing.

```
holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBX_8888);
```

setting to RGB_888

```
holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_888);
```

leads to nullpointerexceptions when i draw something

only the combination of Config.RGB_565 for the bitmap and PixelFormat.RGB_565 for the window
draws the bitmap in acceptable 10ms to the canvas, but the quality of RGB_565 is horrilble.

am I missing something? is Google TV not capable of 32bit graphics? what is its "natural" pixel and bitmap format? Is there any documentation on this topic i missed on google?

here my requested onDraw method i use to measure the timings:

```
private static void doDraw(Canvas c) {

        if (LevelBitmap.level == null){
            LevelBitmap.createBitmap();
        }

        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        c.drawBitmap(LevelBitmap.level, 0, 0, null);
        Log.e("Timer:",""+(System.currentTimeMillis()-time) );
        if(true) return;
```

and here the class creating the bitmap:

```
public final class LevelBitmap {

    public static Bitmap    level;

    public static void createBitmap() {
        level = Bitmap.createBitmap(GameViewThread.mCanvasHeight, GameViewThread.mCanvasHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(level);

        canvas.scale(GameViewThread.fieldScaleFactor, GameViewThread.fieldScaleFactor);
        canvas.translate(500, 500);

        // floor covering
        int plankWidth = 50;
        int plankSpace = 500;
        short size = TronStatics.FIELDSIZE;
        for (int i = plankSpace; i < size; i = i + plankSpace) {
            canvas.drawRect(i, 0, i + plankWidth, size, GameViewThread.bgGrey);
            canvas.drawRect(0, i, size, i + plankWidth, GameViewThread.bgGrey);
        }

        // draw field
        canvas.drawRect(-10, -10, TronStatics.FIELDSIZE + 10, TronStatics.FIELDSIZE + 10, GameViewThread.wallPaint);

    }

}
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, shape drawing is not all that fast in Android normally (though much better with hardware acceleration on). Have you tried to do some measurements with pure bitmaps?

Comment: this is pure bitmap drawing, I prepare the bitmap in initialization of my LevelBitmap class, the times measured are drawing it into the canvas I get from mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null) only :(

Comment: Could you include the code for your whole draw method here, there may be something else going on besides the actual drawing. Have you tried commenting out all the draw calls but leaving all other code untouched, just to verify it's the bitmap drawing that's slow?

Comment: Also, please mention the device you are working on.

Comment: I added the requested parts. doDraw() is called in a standard while(true) loop with the canvas from mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
the device I'm using is a sony NSZ-GS7, the display output is FullHD, so mCanvasHeight is around 1080.

Comment: Looking at how you are doing the elapsed time measurment I can see that you are not measuring what you think you are measuring. Please refer to: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html

Comment: ok, but its still slow. any idea how i could speed it up? is the combination of Config.RGB_565 for the bitmap and PixelFormat.RGB_565 the fastest on that device? 
Is my approach of drawBitmap for the background and then draw the action ontop simply the wrong way? is it possible to set a reference-bitmap to the surfaceview, so that lockCanvas() would serve me a canvas with that bitmap preset as background?